# Multiplication of big big integers found in string without using external libraries, C++

Tags: c++, string, bigint

So I've been reading several topics about how GNU and other libraries are needed for multiplication of large large numbers, but I am working on something where I can't use large external libraries. Therefore, I went with the approach of inputting the big numbers as strings and I was able to perform on these numbers what I wanted to but now I have come to the hard part: multiplication of two integers up to 50 digits each. Is there any kind of code I can find around~200 or less lines that I can implement in my code and can allow me to do this? Or is there an easy way to implement this multiplication by splitting these numbers? Some thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A way I have done this in the past is to create an array of integers for the arbitrarily sized  numbers. 50 decimal digits requires around 167 bits, or a little over 20 bytes. Round up to 24  so it fits nicely in an array of 32-bit integers. Then convert your decimal strings into 24 bit integers a and b. From there, you can effectively just do the multiplication the same way you were taught to do it by hand. Assuming you already have a function that will add these numbers, you can multiply them like so:

```
int32_t a[6];
int32_t b[6];

// multiplication results require twice as much space as the operands
int32_t result[12];
memset(&result, 0, sizeof(12));

int32_t temp_result[6][7];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        int64_t product = a[i] * b[j];
        temp_result[i][j] = product & (0xffffffff);
        temp_result[i][j + 1] = product & (0xffffffff00000000);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    //  source a,       source b,  result
    add(temp_result[i], result[i], result[i]);
}
```

If you don't already have an add function, the process is very similar.

Comment: int can't be assumed 32 bits. I'd use uint32_t

Answer (score 0):

mini-gmp (small single .c and .h file, part of the full gmp package).

boot multiprecision (not so small but header-only).

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?